# ServiceStack Map Errors in ResponseStatus to custom Errors without Validators

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way in Servicestack to Map custom request validation errors to the errors field in resposeStatus object with out using Validators.

ie. if I have a custom list of errors with a

```
{
    "ErrorCode": "NotEmpty",
    "FieldName": "Company",
    "Message": "'Company' should not be empty."
}
```

How do I map to ResponseStatus object with out Validators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack Exceptions are just Response DTO's that have a populated `ResponseStatus` that are returned with a HTTP Error code. There are a number of different ways you can customize the Error Response including:

### Returning a HttpError with a populated Response DTO

If you want to send a customized ResponseStatus DTO you can throw a HttpError, e.g:

```
var responseDto = new ErrorResponse { 
    ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus {
        ErrorCode = typeof(ArgumentException).Name,
        Message = "Invalid Request",
        Errors = new List<ResponseError> {
            new ResponseError {
                ErrorCode = "NotEmpty",
                FieldName = "Company",
                Message = "'Company' should not be empty."
            }
        }
    }
};
throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "ArgumentException") {
    Response = responseDto,
};
```

### Overriding OnExceptionTypeFilter in your AppHost

By default when you throw an `ArgumentException` the built-in `OnExceptionTypeFilter` will automatically add a populated `ResponseError` for the specified ParamName, e.g:

```
public virtual void OnExceptionTypeFilter(
    Exception ex, ResponseStatus responseStatus)
{
    var argEx = ex as ArgumentException;
    var isValidationSummaryEx = argEx is ValidationException;
    if (argEx != null && !isValidationSummaryEx && argEx.ParamName != null)
    {
        var paramMsgIndex = argEx.Message.LastIndexOf("Parameter name:");
        var errorMsg = paramMsgIndex > 0
            ? argEx.Message.Substring(0, paramMsgIndex)
            : argEx.Message;

        responseStatus.Errors.Add(new ResponseError
        {
            ErrorCode = ex.GetType().Name,
            FieldName = argEx.ParamName,
            Message = errorMsg,
        });
    }
}
```

You can also override this method in your AppHost to customize the ResponseStatus of your own exceptions.

### Implementing `IResponseStatusConvertible`

Behind the scenes the way `ValidationException` allows customizing the Response DTO is by [having ValidationException implement](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/773aac107fc2e0fe6a823acef0c3bad20f686da0/src/ServiceStack/FluentValidation/ValidationException.cs#L41) the [IResponseStatusConvertible](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Model/IResponseStatusConvertible.cs#L7) interface.

E.g. Here's how to create a custom Exception that throws a populated Field Error in the Response DTO:

```
public class CustomFieldException : Exception, IResponseStatusConvertible
{
  ...
    public string FieldErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldMessage { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ToResponseStatus()
    {
        return new ResponseStatus {
            ErrorCode = GetType().Name,
            Message = Message,
            Errors = new List<ResponseError> {
                new ResponseError {
                    ErrorCode = FieldErrorCode,
                    FieldName = FieldName,
                    Message = FieldMessage
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```